# Angular ui-router state name binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to bind a function to specific state name instead of the state change event?

For example, this is what I do now:

```
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    console.log(toState.name);
  });
```

Basically, I bind to `$stateChangeSuccess` and get `toState.name` to process a specific task. But I feel this is a bit **overkill** as it binds to a general event. I just want to bind to a specific state such as `toState.name = "foo"` or something like that.

Any pointer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here: [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

> All these `events` are fired at the `$rootScope` level.

I would say, this is the advantage of this kind of eventing system. It allows us to hook on some functionality as a standard **AOP framework** *(Regardless of the specific state beeing navigated to)*.

Using the `if` or `switch` with combination of multiple files/listeners... could make it clear and managable.

*Side NOTE: I do prefer to has one (if possible) file for an aspect, to use suffix e.g. (ctrl.js, dirc.js, listner.js) to distinguish the kind.*

Comment: So if I have 20 controllers all subscribed to `$stateChangeStart` but they require different `state.name` to act upon, isn't that a little **bloated** in the event loop somewhere (in term of performance)? Or my worry is non-sense?

Comment: Please, read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/1679310 about more details about the performance. I would hardly explain that better ;) Summary: 20 is not an issue ;) I would say, prefere better code maintainance (searching, extending) over too much performance improvements (if reasonable;). The AOP(event listeners) placed outside of the standard implementation, even with some overhead to process 20 of them, will give us lot of profit later.. once the application is mature (and large)